# POST is not working in CodeIgniter while GET works perfectly fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm facing this issue with POST in CodeIgniter which is not working while if I switch to GET, that works fine.

**Login Controller**

```
public function login_check(){
    print_r($this->input->post());
    if($this->input->post('email')!=NULL){
        echo '1';
    }
    else{
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( array('a' => $this->input->post('email')));
}
```

CSRF is set to false in config file, while base url is set to http://localhost/xyz/

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Routes**

```
$route['api/login-check'] = 'login/login_check';
```

If I set `$this->input->get('email')` while setting method GET in postman, that works absolutely okay.

What's something that I'm missing? Any help in this will be appreciated.

EDIT:

**Response from postman:**

```
Array() {"a":null}
```

Comment: can you add the associated code from the rest API?

Comment: I have added response from postman. For now, this is the only code that I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is doing exactly as you are asking it to do.

A break down of your code goes like...

```
If I get something from $this->input->post('email') then 
     echo '1';
else if $this->input->post('email') is NULL
     then assign NULL to a and return it in a json_encoded array.
```

Going by your code it might meant to be something like...

```
public function login_check(){
    print_r($this->input->post());
    if($this->input->post('email') == NULL){ // This was != 
        echo '1';
    }
    else{
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( array('a' => $this->input->post('email')));
}
```

The Only change being to alter != to == in your if statement.

One of those "stare at it too long and never see it" simple Logic Error :)

**A better recommendation is to use something like...**

```
public function login_check(){
    print_r($this->input->post());

    if($this->input->post('email')){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode( array('a' => $this->input->post('email')));
        exit();
    }
    else {
        // Handle the case where no email was entered.
        echo '1';
    }
}
```

That should get you back on track.

**Update:** I have tried this in postman (just installed it ) and for a POST you need to set the key/value under Body and not Headers as you do with GET, if that's something you were also missing.

Comment: That's something I was missing. Thanks for your help.